# Define a identical height for two tables

Tags: html, css

I have two seperate tables [on my website](http://wiki.vocaloid.de/Pinocchio-P#Originale_Alben), which contain a total of 10 albums. Both of them have the same CSS values, but differ in their content. Therefore their height is unequal.

My goal is to make the tables end at the same horizontal line, while the images have a identical size.

Theoretically, I could set my CSS file to `td, th {width: 115px;}`, so that the tables end at the same position. But the problem is, my tables are generated by a template, which means next time my tables could possibly contain a total of 20 albums, so that this trick won't work.

I need to find a way to **dynamically set the height for both tables**. And the **images** should be also in the **same size**. Please check my website for finding a ideal solution.

[image: Table with different height]

Comment: A) make the boxes [1-10] same height (looks more professional) b) use jquery or javascript

Comment: Can't you just set `height: 100px` on the images, and let them scale up/down accordingly? This will give your cells constant height (since the images are the biggest thing there) and in theory constant table height.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol No, because it is not clear, how many albums will be in the table. In case there are about 100 albums with the ´height:100px´ it would be squeezed

Comment: Apparently you want us to do your work, without showing any effort on your side.

Comment: Well as I said, I tried it using width, max-height and several other css attributes

Comment: I said on the images themselves, not the table. In fact, it's exactly what @AmodeusNOIR has suggested in an answer that's getting downvoted despite being, in my opinion, perfectly correct.

Comment: Guess, you did not check my website, did you? I tried setting the image width and height to 90px each, but it gets squeezed. I really tried my best, but it seems like the margin of td is responsible for this..

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol read answer again before saying anymore.. why you get +189K rep is unclear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine creating a css class for each of the images being the same size would then push the rest of the tables to match up with each other.

Edit: Had a little look, and you're correct, seems to be squashing the images, though the code really shouldn't be. Rather than adding an '!important' tag to the end of the css height, please see the amended code below.

Like:

```css
#tableID td img { width: 100%; max-width:90px; height: auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you. At least one person who wants to help me, after I wrote a text with 200 words describing my situation. (If I would had known it, I wouldn't ask!)

Comment: Not a problem. Hopefully this helped you out, though I have a feeling there may be a bit more development (perhaps some javascript/jquery) needed to make it fully responsive to your varied amount of covers!

Did it help at all?